# Read CSV with more than 22 colums in Apache Flink

Tags: scala, csv, apache-flink

What I've been doing until now is read CSV as follows:

```
val data = env.readCsvFile[ElecNormNew](getClass.getResource("/elecNormNew.arff").getPath)

val dataSet = data map { tuple =>
      val list = tuple.productIterator.toList
      val numList = list map (_.asInstanceOf[Double])
      LabeledVector(numList(8), DenseVector(numList.take(8).toArray))
    }
```

Where `ElecNorNew` is a `case class`:

```
case class ElecNormNew(
  var date: Double,
  var day: Double,
  var period: Double,
  var nswprice: Double,
  var nswdemand: Double,
  var vicprice: Double,
  var vicdemand: Double,
  var transfer: Double,
  var label: Double) extends Serializable {
}
```

As specified in [Flink's docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/dev/batch/#data-sources). But now I am trying to read a CSV with 53 columns. Is there a way to automate this process? Do I need to create a POJO with 53 fields?

### Update

After Fabian's answer, I am trying this:

```
val fieldTypes: Array[TypeInformation[_]] = Array(Types.STRING, Types.INT)
  val rowIF = new RowCsvInputFormat(new Path(getClass.getResource("/lungcancer.csv").getPath), fieldTypes)
  val csvData: DataSet[Row] = env.createInput[Row](rowIF)
  val dataSet2 = csvData.map { tuple =>
      ???
  }
```

But do not know how to continue, how I am suppose to use `RowTypeInfo`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `RowCsvInputFormat` as follows:

```
val fieldTypes: Array[TypeInformation[_]] = Array(Types.STRING, Types.INT)

val rowIF = new RowCsvInputFormat(new Path("file:///myCsv"), fieldTypes)
val csvData: DataSet[Row] = env.createInput[Row](rowIF)
```

`Row` stores the data in an `Array[Any]`. Therefore, Flink cannot automatically infer the field types of a `Row`. This makes is a bit harder to use than typed tuples or case classes. You need to explicitly provide `RowTypeInfo` with the correct types. This can be done as implicit values or by functions that extend the `ResultTypeQueryable` interface.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question, coul you please show me how to use `RowTypeInfo`, I could not find any documentation on flink's web.